# About Estimating Parameters from Unpaired Datasets

Tags: regression, estimation, linear, parameterization, piecewise-linear

I possess three datasets: $x$, $y$ and $z$. It's hypothesized that a relationship exists between these variables, represented by the equation $z=a*x+b*y$.

My goal is to estimate the values of $a$ and $b$. However, the datasets aren't inherently paired, meaning there isn't a straightforward one-to-one correlation among each data. Given the ambiguity in matching specific $x$ and $y$ values to generate a particular $z$, traditional linear regression doesn't seem to be a viable approach.

Are there any suggestions to address this challenge? I appreciate any guidance.